# Make Google +1 button +1 a specific URL rather than the URL it's on?

Tags: google-plus-one

Can I make a Google +1 button +1 a specific URL - e.g. my front page, http://www.givingwhatwecan.org/ - rather than the URL the button's on? I've [read](http://www.nicheprofitclassroom.com/blog/google-1/) that you can do this by putting that URL between the g:plusone tags like so:

```
<g:plusone>http://www.givingwhatwecan.org/</g:plusone>
```

However I've done this on both http://gwwc2.centreforeffectivealtruism.org/ & http://gwwc2.centreforeffectivealtruism.org/resources/index.php and it only seems to work on [the former](http://gwwc2.centreforeffectivealtruism.org/) - if you click the +1 button on [the latter](http://gwwc2.centreforeffectivealtruism.org/resources/index.php), you'll be +1ing http://gwwc2.centreforeffectivealtruism.org/resources/index.php rather than http://www.givingwhatwecan.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code snippet does not match the one over at NicheProfit. (Though it does match the *description*, which is inaccurate.)

The custom URL is added as an href attribute on the `g:plusone` element:

```
<g:plusone href="http://www.example.com/"></g:plusone>
```

Alternately, just use [Google's code generator](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/), pop open the Advanced Options toggle, and fill out the "URL to +1:" field.

And here's the actual [documentation on setting a target URL](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#target-url).

Disregard your two examples behaving differently. They're just wrong in the first place, so not worth debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The new api requires that you do something like this:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-href="http://domain.tld/example"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Any user's want to show individual G+ button for different post/pages then they should recommend to use this code:

//where to show 1+ button...

```
<g:plusone expr:href="data:post.url" size="medium" annotation="bubble"></g:plusone>
```

and paste this below code before `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement(&#39;script&#39;); po.type = &#39;text/javascript&#39;; po.async = true;
        po.src = &#39;https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js&#39;;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;script&#39;)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```