# Make Google Plus One only work for the domain and not the path

Tags: search-results, google-plus-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Google +1 button +1 a specific URL rather than the URL it's on?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/make-google-1-button-1-a-specific-url-rather-than-the-url-its-on)

I'm creating an image sharing website, and since it's going to have many thousand links, then it's almost impossible to put a Google Plus One button in my site. Plus one is an indication of site's popularity and trust. You follow a link in SERP, because you see that somebody that you know has already plused one that link. So, you trust that link and click it.

The more plus a page get, the more trustworthy it becomes. Sites which has simple static pages can get many plus ones, but sites like mine (dynamic sites with thousands of links) can't aggregate plus ones in one page.

Is there any way to tell Google that I only want the Plus Ones to be counted for the **domain** only, and not for the **path**? In other words, how can I transfer a plus one given to the **http://example.com/tag1-tag2/2525** to plus ones given to the **http://example.com**? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Do you mean this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303634/google-1-count-for-my-homepage-not-for-all-subpages

?

Comment: @milo5b, that was the exact answer I wanted. Post it as an answer, so that I can choose it.